# Perfect information game with heap of objects

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I have to find the winning strategy for the following game. There is a heap with $N$ objects. Two players take objects in turn, but there is a limitation: if there were taken $K$ objects on previous turn, then player can take only $K$ or $K + 1$ objects on current turn. On the first turn a player can take 1 or 2 objects. The one to make the last turn is the winner.

I've written a simple program using dynamic programming that calculates a winner for different values of $N$. There are some of them:

```
N winner
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 1
6 2
7 1
8 1
9 1
10 2
11 1
12 1
13 2
14 1
15 2
16 1
17 1
18 2
19 1
20 1
```

Actually I couldn't find any pattern in this sequence (for $N \le 100$). Also the distance between adjacent second players' winning positions doesn't exceed $4$, but I can't explain that.

Maybe this problem can be reduced to nim somehow...

Comment: I assume that if a player is unable to take *exactly* $K$ or $K+1$ objects (because there are fewer than $K$ objects remaining), that player loses, yes?

Comment: @Brian: Yes: you can confirm it by the fact that Player 1 is given as the winner for $n=3$.

Comment: Can you give more of the sequence?  (It would suffice to list the N's for which player 2 is the winner.)

Comment: 4,6,10,13,15,18,22,24,28,30,33,35,37,40,42,46,49,51,54,56,58,61,65,67,70,73,75,78,82,84,88,92,94,97

Comment: @perlik,  thank you.  The first few numbers, 4,6,10,13,15,18 (from the OP) had a couple of hits at the OEIS, but they go away with the next couple of terms.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I presumed so, but thought it would be good to confirm (just in case OP had miscalculated).

Comment: I'm plotting the results for state $(M, K)$, where $M$ is the number of objects remaining at the start of a player's turn, and $K$ is the number of objects taken by the previous player (or $K = 1$ if this is the first turn).  This yields some interesting patterns.

Comment: The binary function $w(M, K)$, which returns $1$ if $(M, K)$ is a winning state, and $0$ otherwise, has a basis case set $w(M, K) = 0$ if $M < K$; otherwise, the recursion is $w(M, K) = 1-w(M-K, K)w(M-K-1, K+1)$.  The list of numbers above are those values $M$ for which $w(M, 1) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not a solution;** it’s a way of looking at the game that may provide some insight, together with some possibly useful data.

This can be viewed as a game played on a grid. You start at $\langle n,1\rangle$; if you’re at $\langle k,\ell\rangle$, the possible moves are to $\langle k-\ell,\ell\rangle$ and to $\langle k-\ell-1,\ell+1\rangle$. If $k<\ell$, no move is possible, and you lose. Clearly you want to avoid moving to a point $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ with $\ell\le k\le 2\ell+1$: if $k=\ell$, your opponent will move to $\langle 0,\ell\rangle$, and in all other cases your opponent will move to $\langle k-\ell-1,\ell+1\rangle$, and you’ll have no legal move. Using $1$ for a position in which the player whose turn it is has a winning move (i.e., an N-position in the usual terminology), and $2$ for a position in which the other player wins (a P-position), some of the grid looks like this:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
7&2&2&2&2&2&2&2&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2\\
6&2&2&2&2&2&2&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&2&2\\
5&2&2&2&2&2&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&2&2&2&2\\
4&2&2&2&2&1&1&1&1&1&1&2&2&2&2&1&1&1\\
3&2&2&2&1&1&1&1&1&2&2&2&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
2&2&2&1&1&1&1&2&2&1&1&2&1&1&1&2&2&1\\
1&2&1&1&1&2&1&2&1&1&1&2&1&1&2&1&2&1\\ \hline
\ell\backslash k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16
\end{array}$$

It’s clear that $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ is a P-position if $0\le k<\ell$, and it’s not hard to verify that $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ is an N-position if $\ell\le k\le 2\ell+1$ and a P-position if $2\ell+2\le k\le 3\ell+1$. Moreover, if $k<\binom{n+1}2$, then $k\le\sum_{i=2}^ni$, and from the position $\langle k,1\rangle$ we can go no higher than $\ell=n$ (and that only at $\langle 0,n\rangle$). In fact we’ll cross the line $k=3\ell+1$ sooner than that, there’s a pretty efficient algorithm for determining whether $\langle k,1\rangle$ is an N- or a P-position.

Comment: This is essentially the same diagram that I produced (albeit upside-down).  There are even some obvious regularities in the upper left half of the grid.  Unfortunately, things get a little chaotic as we descend toward the lower right...

Comment: @Brian: It is indeed; I was typing and didn’t see any of those comments.

Comment: No worries; I'm just glad someone else went through the trouble of typing it up. :-)